# inserting items in list in mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a document like this

```
{ "_id" : "decfed9a04b997d", "pushed_list" : [ ] }
```

and I want to update/insert "pushed_list" by these sub items stored in a python list

```
lis1 = 
    [
       {
        item : 'item1',
        desc : 'desc_item1'
       },
       {
        item : 'item2',
        desc : 'desc_item2'
       },
       { ........................
       }

    ]
```

I tried this

```
db.monitor.update({'_id' : 'dbjkdd'}, { '$push':{'pushed_list': {'$each':{lis1}}}})
```

Its giving me an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "monitor.py", line 13, in <module>
    db.monitor.update({'_id' : 'dbjfdd'}, { '$push':{'pushed_list': {'$each':{lis1}}}})
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer, pretty foolish on my side; just have to remove extra braces `{}`

Instead of this

```
db.monitor.update({'_id' : 'dbjkdd'}, { '$push':{'pushed_list': {'$each':{lis1}}}})
```

Use this

```
db.monitor.update({'_id' : 'dbjkdd'}, { '$push':{'pushed_list': {'$each':lis1}}})
```

i.e remove `'{'`after `'$each'` and its corresponding `'}'`

Comment: NoSQL DBs are just soooo simple