# Append new value to a list in PyMongo

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo, mlab

I have a collection in MongoDB that I store on mlab like this

```
{
   'course_id': '...',
   'course_description: '...',
   'reviews:' [
      {
         'hours': ...
         'review': ...
      },
      {
         'hours': ...
         'review': ...
      }
    ]
}
```

I'm having trouble appending new values to the `list_to_append` above. None of these methods below works for me. I'm using PyMongo (version 2.8) to interact with MongoDB.

Here is the code snippet that I'm using to update the list

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    search_form = SearchBar()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        review_dict = {'hours': "5 hours", 'review': "Something something"}

        # Test with one collection and one course first
        mongo.db['CS'].update({'course_id:': 'CS 101'}, {'$push': {'reviews:': review_dict}})
        return render_template('index.html', form=search_form)
```

I've tried these methods below but they didn't work for me.

[Append item to MongoDB document array in PyMongo without re-insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189258/append-item-to-mongodb-document-array-in-pymongo-without-re-insertion)

[How to insert an element to MongoDB internal list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987365/how-to-insert-an-element-to-mongodb-internal-list)

[inserting items in list in mongodb document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674352/inserting-items-in-list-in-mongodb-document)

Comment: What specific problem(s) are you having? Why don't the solutions to those questions work for you?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working. I'm sure I'm using the right collection to update. The new element/value did not seem to be appended to the list on mlab.

Comment: At this point you'll need to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40706645/edit) your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without seeing what you're doing, it's hard to tell you why it isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.